# What should I put in redirect_uri for implicit OAuth 2.0

Tags: support, api, oauth2, ios

From the [document](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication#scope) I can't figure out what value should I put in redirect_uri if I want to implement iPhone app. I try https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success but it not work and show this error

```
Application Login Failure
An error occurred while login into an application.

Error Details

error: 0
error description: redirect_uri is not under the registered domain for this application
```

**Updated**

I unchecked `Disable Desktop Application OAuth Redirect Uri` and now it show `Authorizing Application`. How can my app know if login success ? is there a way to redirect to my app via [URL scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) ?

Comment: Related: http://stackapps.com/questions/6530/unable-to-get-access-token