# Unable to get access token

Tags: support, api, api-v2, authentication, oauth2

I am trying to get a non-expiry access token, like so:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth?scope=no_expiry&redirect_uri={{some_uri}}&client_id={{some_value}}
```

I am repeatedly getting the error:

> **Application Login Failure**
>   An error occurred while login into an application.
>
> **Error Details**
>   error description: Cannot return to provided redirect_uri

I have tried several values for `redirect_uri, such as:

- `https://www.yahoo.com/`
  and
- `10.**.**.**/myscript.php`

None of them seem to be working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Refer to [the Stack Exchange API, **Authentication** docs](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).  It *looks* like you are trying to authenticate using either a server you do not control, or a local server that is not on the public internet.

Crucial Points:

1. **Do not specify a `redirect_uri` to any server that you do not control.**
   When you use something like `redirect_uri=https://www.yahoo.com/`, then a third party host has you, or your user's, credentials!  That page/server will see a request like:

   ```
   https://www.yahoo.com/#access_token=X0duhxxxxxxxxxxxNvfDbQ%29%29&expires=86399
   ```

   It can then use that `access_token` to do unspeakable evil.

   **This is a major breach of both security and trust.**  <sub>(Frankly, if you or your app are caught doing this, lifetime bans should be issued.  Legal action may even be appropriate in some cases.)</sub>
2. The value you **[set for `OAuth Domain`](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/) must match the `redirect_uri`.**

   So, if you use, `redirect_uri=http://10.0.0.86/myscript.php`,
   then you must set `OAuth Domain` to `10.0.0.86`.
3. **If you do not have your own server**:

   1. Use the "implicit OAuth 2.0 flow" (Client side).  Activate `Enable Client Side OAuth Flow` in your app's control panel.
   2. Leave `Disable Desktop Application OAuth Redirect Uri` unchecked.
   3. Set `OAuth Domain` to `stackexchange.com`.
   4. Use `redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success`.
4. Be sure to use `GET` requests for implicit (client side) OAuth and `POST` for explicit (server-side) OAuth.

When the authentication is successful, the `access_token` will be in the `location.hash` of the redirected page.  For example:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=5bcPtLjiyuySD7WeKSo3Mw))&expires=86399
```

Comment: So i just need security token for one time. Instagram/Facebook use any redirect_uri and provide token on the URL itself. StackApps following the same model, i was expecting that any URL should work. Will try the point 2/3 and will update. Thanks for answering.

Comment: The token *is* returned in the URL (hash). And, even for Instagram/Facebook it's a major security breach to use a 3rd-party URL.